# blockSignals is not working for QGraphicsScene selectionChanged

Tags: python, pyqt5

The `selectionChanged` signal is firing after I deselect the selected item, despite calling `blockSignals(True)` just before. You can see that the circle will be moved twice instead of once. Why is this happening and how do I prevent the signal from firing?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Template(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 200, 400)
        c = self.scene.addEllipse(8, 8, 34, 34, Qt.black, Qt.black)
        c.setPos(0, 350)
        c.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.scene.selectionChanged.connect(self.move)
        
        view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)        

    def move(self):
        selected = self.scene.selectedItems()
        if selected:
            selected[0].moveBy(0, -50)
            self.scene.blockSignals(True)
            selected[0].setSelected(False)
            self.scene.blockSignals(False)

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Template()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Let me also specify that I'm not interested in this specific example, there are plenty of workarounds to move the circle as desired. It was just to provide a visualization.

**I'm interested in the general case: The `selectionChanged` signal is connected to a slot, and in that function you need to deselect an item without the slot being invoked again.**

Comment: Why do you need to immediately deselect the item? Is your purpose to call `move` only when the item is clicked? If that's the case, you should not use the selection.

Comment: Yes, an "itemClicked" logic obviously makes more sense here. I was just curious why it was double firing and wanted to present a very small and simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the mouse since after executing the logic of moving the mouse it is still on the item causing its selection generating that double shot. A possible solution is to deselect after the mouse is released.

```py
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        for item in self.selectedItems():
            item.setSelected(False)
        self.blockSignals(False)


class Template(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = GraphicsScene(0, 0, 200, 400, self)
        self.scene.selectionChanged.connect(self.handle_selection_changed)

        c = self.scene.addEllipse(8, 8, 34, 34, Qt.black, Qt.black)
        c.setPos(0, 350)
        c.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

        view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)

    def handle_selection_changed(self):
        self.scene.blockSignals(True)
        for item in self.scene.selectedItems():
            item.moveBy(0, -50)
```